# Elasticsearch - How to get min/max/avg of set of nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Given the following mapping and documents in Elasticsearch, how would I get the min/max/avg of a set of nested documents that match a certain condition?  For instance, how would I get them min age of pet that are dogs?  My filter gets the correct people that have dogs, but how do I make the min then calculate against the correct nested documents.

(1) Mapping

```
{
   "myIndex": {
      "mappings": {
         "person": {
            "properties": {
               "name": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "pets": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "age": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

(2) Data

```
{
  "name": "bob",
  "pets": [
    {
      "type": "dog",
      "name": "wolfie",
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "type": "cat",
      "name": "kitty",
      "age": 6
    }
  ]
}

{
  "name": "bill",
  "pets": [
    {
      "type": "fish",
      "name": "goldie",
      "age": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "cat",
      "name": "meowie",
      "age": 18
    }
  ]
}
```

(3) Query and aggregation

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "pets",
          "filter" : {
            "terms": {
              "pets.type": ["dog"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "minage": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "pets"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "minage": {
          "min": {
            "field": "age"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get what you want with a combination of [filter aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) and the nested filter's [join option](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-filter.html#_join_option).

This code worked for me:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
       "person": {
            "properties": {
               "name": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "pets": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "age": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
   }
}

PUT /test_index/person/1
{
  "name": "bob",
  "pets": [
    {
      "type": "dog",
      "name": "wolfie",
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "type": "cat",
      "name": "kitty",
      "age": 6
    }
  ]
}

PUT /test_index/person/2
{
  "name": "bill",
  "pets": [
    {
      "type": "fish",
      "name": "goldie",
      "age": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "cat",
      "name": "meowie",
      "age": 18
    }
  ]
}

PUT /test_index/person/3
{
  "name": "john",
  "pets": [
    {
      "type": "dog",
      "name": "oldie",
      "age": 25
    }
  ]
}

POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "minage_1": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "pets"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "minage_2": {
               "filter": {
                  "nested": {
                     "path": "pets",
                     "filter": {
                        "terms": {
                           "pets.type": [
                              "dog"
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     "join": false
                  }
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "min_age_3": {
                     "min": {
                        "field": "age"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "minage_1": {
         "doc_count": 5,
         "minage_2": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "min_age_3": {
               "value": 20
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to the filter aggregration. That did the trick. In your example, the inner minage_2 nesting seems redundant, and I didn't need the join. "aggs": { "dog": { "filter": { "term": { "type": "dog" } }, "aggs": {"minage": {"min": {"field": "age"} } } } }

Comment: Hmm, that combination doesn't work for me, for some reason. So something's different somewhere. Anyway, glad it helped. I learned something along the way too.

Comment: Hmm. I must have misread my results because my slimmed down aggregation didn't produce the correct results and yours did.  The outermost minage_1 nested aggregation just seems weird to me, and it seems to be for the minage_3 aggregation on age, so why can't it be put down there?

Comment: hello sir @SloanAhrens are you still active? hope you don't mind helping me out with this inquiry? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797633/elastcisearch-how-to-get-the-last-nested-object-of-all-documents-then-perform