# (Elasticsearch) How to get the last element of a nested field of all documents then perform sub-aggregations

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have an index called **socialmedia** and trying to create queries with this field called **eng** (omitted some unnecessary fields)

```
"id" : "1",
"eng": 
[
{
  "soc_mm_score" : "3",
  "date_updated" : "1520969306",
},
{
  "soc_mm_score" : "1",
  "date_updated" : "1520972191",
},
{
  "soc_mm_score" : "4",
  "date_updated" : "1520937222",
}
]
```

I have **a lot** of documents from this index that contains **eng** nested field that also contains a lot of "sub-objects"

Now, my main goal is, what Elasticsearch query should I formulate to filter out these nested objects

**STEP 1** 
Get the nested object with the highest **date_updated** value

**STEP 2** 
After getting those nested objects, perform a **sum** aggregation so I could add all the values of the **soc_mm_score** field for the corresponding **"latest nested object"**

I have tried this query but seems to fail

**ATTEMPT # 1** (I'm using elasticsearch-php API so please trust my query that it's working with this format)

```
'aggs' => [
    'ENG' => [
        'nested' => [
            'path' => 'eng'
        ],
        'aggs' => [
            'FILTER' => [
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            [
                                // I'm thinking of using max aggregation here
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            'LATEST' => [
                'top_hits' => [
                    'size' => 1,
                    'sort' => [
                        'eng.date_updated' => [
                            'order' => 'desc'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

PRO/S: it is returning the correct nested object
CON/S: I cannot perform further aggregations

Sample Output 
[image: Output 1]

Then I tried adding sub-aggregation 
[image: Output 2]

Then this is the output
[image: Output 3]

Is there any other ways that I can perform this?

To review my ideal steps:

1. Access my **eng** nested field
2. Get the "latest" / most recent element for that **eng** nested field (indicated by the element with the highest value of **date_updated** field)
3. Now, after getting those "most recent" nested elements, make sub-aggregations for its sibling nested fields, for example: getting the sum of the **soc_like_count** or **soc_share_count** of all the most recent element of the **eng** field

Comment: Did you get the answer?Please share.

Comment: unfortunately, there's no answer yet @trusha :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709347/sum-over-top-hits-aggregation

Comment: so far, my nearest hint is this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709347/sum-over-top-hits-aggregation provided by sir Assael, however, I'm trying to manipulate nested field, and the "sum_bucket" portion doesn't seem able to read each other

Comment: can I tag somebody who hasn't commented? hello sir @Val

Comment: Can you provide a few sample documents and the expected answer?

Comment: hello sir @Val, here are some documents from the index: https://codeshare.io/aVwQ0b

here, you can see 3 documents and we'll focus on the **eng**  nested field, please expect that the **eng** nested field will be filled with a lot of objects in the future

Comment: Can you share documents which have several elements in the `eng` array since this is the whole purpose of the question.

Comment: My goal is, create an aggregation query to always look at the "latest" object PER DOCUMENT which is determined by the **date_updated** nested field of **eng**, and then sum the sibling nested fields such as "soc_like_count" or "soc_share_count"

Comment: ok sir, for a while

Comment: sir @Val here's my updated codeshare: https://codeshare.io/aVwQ0b

Comment: By "sum the sibling nested fields" you mean the siblings from the same `eng` array in the document, or the other "most recent" `eng` elements?

Comment: siblings from the same eng array in the document, sir

Comment: I mean, MOST RECENT,

Comment: Based on the documents you shared, please show the data you expect to see in the response.

Comment: sir @Val, I have updated the codeshare, I made some changes at the bottom of the  codeshare: https://codeshare.io/aVwQ0b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202306/discussion-between-suomynona-and-val).

Comment: this question is now up for bounty, thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202380/discussion-between-suomynona-and-val).

Comment: hello sir @Val, good day! Any answerts for this one? :(

Comment: @trusha hello, you may try the answer I posted below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formulated an answer!

```
"aggs":{
        "LATEST": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script" : """
                  state.te = []; 
                  state.g = 0;
                  state.d = 0;
                  state.a = 0;
                """, 
                "map_script" : """
                  if(state.d != doc['_id'].value){
                      state.d = doc['_id'].value;
                      state.te.add(state.a);
                      state.g = 0;
                      state.a = 0;
                  } 
                  if(state.g < doc['eng.date_updated'].value){ 
                    state.g = doc['eng.date_updated'].value; 
                    state.a = doc['eng.soc_te_score'].value;
                  }
                  """,
                "combine_script" : """
                    state.te.add(state.a);
                    double count = 0; 
                    for (t in state.te) { 
                      count += t 
                    }

                    return count
                  """,
                "reduce_script" : """
                    double count = 0; 
                    for (a in states) { 
                      count += a 
                    }

                    return count
                """
            }
        }
      }
```

Comment: just change the array index around  this code `state.a = doc['eng.soc_te_score'].value;` to pinpoint or determine which sibling nested fields to be summated for example: `state.a = doc['eng.soc_like_count'].value;`